# How to deal with spurious type script error: types of property $timeout of types base class and derived class are incompatible?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Since upgrading to TypeScript 1.6, I've been getting what appears to be a spurious error with all my ng.Types:

> Typescript 1.6 class 'derivedClass' cannot extend class 'baseClass':
>   types of property $timeout of types base class and derived class are
>   incompatible

Here's the code sample:

```
module app.Test {

    class derivedClass extends baseClass {
        // Notice there's nothing in the derived class
    }

    class baseClass {
        constructor(timeout: ng.ITimeoutService, val1: string, otherVal: ng.ILogService) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.$timeout = timeout;
            vm.someValue = val1;
            vm.otherValue = otherVal;
        }
        $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService; // angular.ITimeoutService works
        someValue: string;
        otherValue: ng.ILogService;
    }
}
```

angular.ITimeoutService works, or adding import ng= angular; in my modules also works. This didn't used to be an issue in the previous versions of Typescript.

Is it best practice to repeat the alias (eg: import ng = angular) in each module before using it, even though that's already done in the angular.d.ts?

Comment: Is this via a new project or an in-place upgrade of TypeScript on an existing project? (might be a newer version of angular.d.ts causing the issue and not v1.6)

Comment: In place upgrade of an existing project. And unfortunately I also upgraded the angular.d.ts file

Answer (score 0):

> Is it best practice to repeat the alias (eg: import ng = angular) in each module before using it, even though that's already done in the angular.d.ts

NO. The error is happening probably because you have done this.

The code you have posted works fine by default:

[image]

Comment: No, the error occurs without the alias. This code used to work like this, until I upgraded to Typescript 1.6 and the latest angular.d.ts files